# Arbitrary-Length Ternary Squarefree Words

Tags: code-golf, string

A string is [squarefree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squarefree_word) if it contains no substring twice in a row.

It is possible to have an arbitrarily long squarefree word using a 3-letter alphabet.

Write a program which accepts a positive integer n from stdin and prints any squarefree word of length n, using characters `A`, `B` and `C`.

Shortest code wins.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### GolfScript (<strike>40</strike> 27 chars)

```
~1,{.{!}%+}2$*1,/<{,65+}%n+
```

The approach is a trivial variant on one of those described in Wikipedia: the run-lengths of 1s in the Thue-Morse sequence.

If the extra trailing newline is unacceptable it can be removed at the cost of one character by replacing `n` with `''`.

Answer (score 6):

### Python, 94

```
n=input()
x=[0]
exec"x+=[1-y for y in x];"*n
print''.join('ABC'[x[i+1]-x[i]]for i in range(n))
```

It uses the Thue–Morse sequence method from wikipedia.

Efficient version (100 chars):

```
n=input()
x=[0]
while x==x[:n]:x+=[1-y for y in x]
print''.join('ABC'[x[i+1]-x[i]]for i in range(n))
```

Comment: `exec"x+=[1-y for y in x];"*n` saves 6 chars at the expense of efficiency - but hey this is golf!

Answer (score 4):

### Python, <strike>129</strike> <strike>125</strike> 119

Using John Leech's method as described on the linked wiki page.

```
s='A'
n=input()
while len(s)<=n:s=''.join('ABCBCACABBCAABCCABBCACABABCBCACABBCAABC'[ord(t)%5::3]for t in s)
print s[:n]
```

Comment: You could save some characters with: `'ABCBCACABBCAABCCABBCACABABCBCACABBCAABC'[ord(t)%5::3]`

Comment: `while s[:n]==s:` saves 1 more

Answer (score 3):

### Python2 - 112 chars

This is pretty inefficient. It generates a *much much much* longer string than required and then truncates it. For example the intermediate `s` for `n=7` is 62748517 (13<sup>n</sup>) characters long

```
s='A'
n=input()
exec"s=''.join('ABCBCACABBCAABCCABBCACABABCBCACABBCAABC'[ord(t)%5::3]for t in s);"*n
print s[:n]
```

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica <strike>159 140</strike>  134

**Edit**: A complete rewrite, using recursion (`NestWhile`).
Much faster and no wasted effort.

**Code**

```
g@n_:=StringTake[NestWhile[#~StringReplace~{"A"-> "ABCBACBCABCBA","B"-> "BCACBACABCACB",
     "C"->"CABACBABCABAC"}&,"ABC",StringLength[#]<n&],n]
```

**Usage**

It takes approximately 1/40 sec to generate a ternary square free word with one million characters.

```
g[10]
g[53]
g[506]
AbsoluteTiming[g[10^6];]
```

[image: results]

**Verifying**

`f` will test whether a string is square free.

```
f[s_]:=StringFreeQ[s, x__~~x__]
```

Checking the above outputs and one case in which the string "CC" appears.

```
f@Out[336]
f@Out[337]
f@Out[338]
f["ABCBACBCABCBABCACBACCABCACBCABACBABCABACBCACBACABCACBA"]
```

> True
> True
> True
> False