# Tips for Golfing in SQLite?

Tags: code-golf, tips, sql

I was looking for this page to help me enhance my first [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/147101/15214) with SQLite, but I couldnt find one. So here we are!

What general tips do you have for golfing in SQLite? I'm looking for ideas that can be applied to code golf problems in general that are at least somewhat specific to SQLite. Please post one tip per answer.

Thanks to Michael B for the idea. :)

Related: [Tips for Golfing in T-SQL?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/32796/tips-for-golfing-in-t-sql)