# Complex permutation

Tags: code-golf, array, permutations

Given an array of integers as input(including negative integers), find all (can include duplicates) permutations that **do not** have the same number next to each other, then print them all out.
If no permutations were found, print Nothing or return an empty list or any consistent output indicating that none were found.
Note that the original array can be a permutation.

Test cases:

```
[0, 1, 1, 0] -> [1, 0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0, 1]
[0, 1, 2, 0] -> [0, 1, 2, 0], [0, 2, 1, 0], [1, 0, 2, 0], [0, 1, 0, 2], [2, 0, 1, 0], [0, 2, 0, 1]
[0, 1, 0] -> [0, 1, 0]
[1, 1, 1] -> [] or Nothing
[0, 0, 1, 1] -> [0, 1, 0, 1], [1, 0, 1, 0]
```

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), all usual golfing rules apply and the shortest answer (in bytes) wins!

Leaderboard:

```js
var QUESTION_ID=244078;
var OVERRIDE_USER=8478;
var ANSWER_FILTER="!t)IWYnsLAZle2tQ3KqrVveCRJfxcRLe",COMMENT_FILTER="!)Q2B_A2kjfAiU78X(md6BoYk",answers=[],answers_hash,answer_ids,answer_page=1,more_answers=!0,comment_page;function answersUrl(d){return"https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/"+QUESTION_ID+"/answers?page="+d+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+ANSWER_FILTER}function commentUrl(d,e){return"https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/"+e.join(";")+"/comments?page="+d+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+COMMENT_FILTER}function getAnswers(){jQuery.ajax({url:answersUrl(answer_page++),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(d){answers.push.apply(answers,d.items),answers_hash=[],answer_ids=[],d.items.forEach(function(e){e.comments=[];var f=+e.share_link.match(/\d+/);answer_ids.push(f),answers_hash[f]=e}),d.has_more||(more_answers=!1),comment_page=1,getComments()}})}function getComments(){jQuery.ajax({url:commentUrl(comment_page++,answer_ids),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(d){d.items.forEach(function(e){e.owner.user_id===OVERRIDE_USER&&answers_hash[e.post_id].comments.push(e)}),d.has_more?getComments():more_answers?getAnswers():process()}})}getAnswers();var SCORE_REG=function(){var d=String.raw`h\d`,e=String.raw`\-?\d+\.?\d*`,f=String.raw`[^\n<>]*`,g=String.raw`<s>${f}</s>|<strike>${f}</strike>|<del>${f}</del>`,h=String.raw`[^\n\d<>]*`,j=String.raw`<[^\n<>]+>`;return new RegExp(String.raw`<${d}>`+String.raw`\s*([^\n,]*[^\s,]),.*?`+String.raw`(${e})`+String.raw`(?=`+String.raw`${h}`+String.raw`(?:(?:${g}|${j})${h})*`+String.raw`</${d}>`+String.raw`)`)}(),OVERRIDE_REG=/^Override\s*header:\s*/i;function getAuthorName(d){return d.owner.display_name}function process(){var d=[];answers.forEach(function(n){var o=n.body;n.comments.forEach(function(q){OVERRIDE_REG.test(q.body)&&(o="<h1>"+q.body.replace(OVERRIDE_REG,"")+"</h1>")});var p=o.match(SCORE_REG);p&&d.push({user:getAuthorName(n),size:+p[2],language:p[1],link:n.share_link})}),d.sort(function(n,o){var p=n.size,q=o.size;return p-q});var e={},f=1,g=null,h=1;d.forEach(function(n){n.size!=g&&(h=f),g=n.size,++f;var o=jQuery("#answer-template").html();o=o.replace("{{PLACE}}",h+".").replace("{{NAME}}",n.user).replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",n.language).replace("{{SIZE}}",n.size).replace("{{LINK}}",n.link),o=jQuery(o),jQuery("#answers").append(o);var p=n.language;p=jQuery("<i>"+n.language+"</i>").text().toLowerCase(),e[p]=e[p]||{lang:n.language,user:n.user,size:n.size,link:n.link,uniq:p}});var j=[];for(var k in e)e.hasOwnProperty(k)&&j.push(e[k]);j.sort(function(n,o){return n.uniq>o.uniq?1:n.uniq<o.uniq?-1:0});for(var l=0;l<j.length;++l){var m=jQuery("#language-template").html(),k=j[l];m=m.replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",k.lang).replace("{{NAME}}",k.user).replace("{{SIZE}}",k.size).replace("{{LINK}}",k.link),m=jQuery(m),jQuery("#languages").append(m)}}
```

```css
body{text-align:left!important}#answer-list{padding:10px;float:left}#language-list{padding:10px;float:left}table thead{font-weight:700}table td{padding:5px}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/codegolf/primary.css?v=f52df912b654"> <div id="language-list"> <h2>Winners by Language</h2> <table class="language-list"> <thead> <tr><td>Language</td><td>User</td><td>Score</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="languages"> </tbody> </table> </div><div id="answer-list"> <h2>Leaderboard</h2> <table class="answer-list"> <thead> <tr><td></td><td>Author</td><td>Language</td><td>Size</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="answers"> </tbody> </table> </div><table style="display: none"> <tbody id="answer-template"> <tr><td>{{PLACE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">{{SIZE}}</a></td></tr></tbody> </table> <table style="display: none"> <tbody id="language-template"> <tr><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">{{SIZE}}</a></td></tr></tbody> </table>
```

Comment: [Welcome to Code Golf](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20861), and nice first question! I'd suggest you remove the `Nothing` output requirement, because it doesn't really make the task more interesting; I think returning an empty list (instead of a lists of lists) is more sensible.

Comment: Could you specify whether or not the result may contain duplicates?

Comment: Are the numbers non-negative integers? Number on it's own is pretty ambiguous but the test cases all contain only positive integers.

Comment: Yes! You can have tuples!

Comment: And also, the numbers can be negative and also be floats.

Comment: @pxeger I made that rule optional.

Comment: Edited as x users requests, removed the floats in input that , i think will be annoying, feel free to rollback if you don't like the edit.

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/241662/66833). These are called "square-free" permutations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 4 bytes

```
Ṗ'¯A
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLhuZYnwq9BIiwiIiwiWzEsMCwxLDJdIl0=)

Port of Jonathan Allan's Jelly answer.

-1 thanks to ovs.

Comment: I think `ṖU'¯A` should work for 5

Comment: @ovs Oh yeah, thanks :)

Comment: You can now remove `U`

Answer (score 3):

## [BQN](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/), 35 bytes<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/mlochbaum/BQN/blob/master/commentary/sbcs.bqn)</sup>

```
{(∧´1«»≠⊢)¨⊸/⍷⊏˜⚇1⍋∘⍋⊸≡˜¨⊸/⥊↕⥊˜≠}
```

[Run online!](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=RiDihpAgeyjiiKfCtDHCq8K74omg4oqiKcKo4oq4L+KNt/Cdlaniio/LnOKahzHijYviiJjijYviirjiiaHLnMKo4oq4L+KliuKGleKlisuc4omg8J2VqX0KCuKImOKAvzHipYpGwqgg4p+oCuKfqDAsIDEsIDEsIDDin6kK4p+oMCwgMSwgMiwgMOKfqQrin6gwLCAxLCAw4p+pCuKfqDEsIDEsIDHin6kK4p+oMCwgMCwgMSwgMeKfqQrin6k=)

Comment: Rules now say "Nothing" part is optional.

Comment: @Jonah thanks for telling me, updated

Answer (score 3):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 30 bytes

```
[:~.@(#~0=1#.2=/\"1])i.@!@#A.]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/o63q9Bw0lOsMbA2V9Yxs9WOUDGM1M/UcFB2UHfVi/2typSZn5CukAXUYKhgpGEC46rq66sgShtgkQMKG2NSDdXBx@TnpKUQb6CgY6igYAV0VqwPmGYEFwDwQjSIHFQDxjMBMQxR9IIHY/wA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 69 bytes

```hs
import Data.List
f=(filter$and.(zipWith(/=)<*>tail)).nub.permutations
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bcqxDsIgEIDhvU9xQwcwBMFZnDq6OxiHM4X0IlBCr4svj8Y4VfNvX/4Jl4ePsTVKZa4MAzLqMy3cBScCRfa1xzxq8aRyIZ7E3snj7sRIUUqd17suvqaVkWnOS0tIGRyMM3RQKmWGHgJcjbLvzG2DYBUcFPz1DdoP2p/TfL29AA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `grouping.extras math.combinatorics`, 59 bytes

```
[ [ [ = ] 2clump-map vnone? ] filter-permutations members ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY67DoJAEEV7vmJ@AAKUGmNpbGyMlaFYNgNuZB/OzhIN4dvXxZhgnFudM7e4nZBsKV7Ox9NhA3ckgwP0ZINTpi/wySQ8aMG3YsSl@QVpdauMSEJJDx7ZgyNkfjlShpN4BDQSPWyzbMog3QQlVCklzD9c//FK1Sfrr/zynMUrLNlBA7Ucgna5Fg5GYw3uk@vUwEi5Q9KBBStr0mbULabtTVyqRXwD)

- `[ ... ] filter-permutations` Select the permutations of the input for which `[ ... ]` returns true.
- `[ = ] 2clump-map` Map `=` to every two elements of a sequence with overlapping. e.g. `{ 1 0 1 1 2 } [ = ] 2clump-map` -> `{ f f t f }`
- `vnone?` Returns true only if every element of a sequence is `f`.
- `members` Get the unique elements of a sequence.

Answer (score 3):

## [PARI/GP](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr), 73 bytes

```
f(x)=r=[];forperm(vecsort(x),p,prod(i=2,#p,p[i]-p[i-1])&&r=concat(r,p));r
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728ILEoMz69YMGCpaUlaboWNz3TNCo0bYtso2Ot0_KLClKLcjXKUpOL84tKgOI6BToFRfkpGpm2RjrKQHZ0ZqwukNA1jNVUUyuyTc7PS04s0SjSKdDUtC6CGLi5oCgzr0QjTSPaQMcQCA1iNTUhMjArAQ)

After a lot of head scratching and asking @alephalpha in chat, here it is.

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 5 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
œʒ¥ĀP
```

Includes duplicated items.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//6ORTkw4tPdIQ8P9/tIGOIRAaxAIA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfeX/o5NPTTq09EhDwP9anf/R0QY6hkBoEKsDZhnBWSAaJGMI5oNVxcYCAA).

**Explanation:**

```python
œ      # Get all permutations of the (implicit) input-list
 ʒ     # Filter it by:
  ¥    #  Get the deltas/forward-differences
   Ā   #  Check for each whether it's NOT 0
    P  #  Product: check if all of them are truthy
       # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

`¥Ā` could alternatively be `üÊ` for the same byte-count:

```python
  ü    #  For each overlapping pair:
   Ê   #   Check that they are not equal
```

Answer (score 3):

## [C++ (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>310</s> <s>301</s> <s>283</s> 278 bytes

EDIT: -22 bytes thanks to `ceilingcat` and -1 byte from the label statement.

```cpp
#include"bits/stdc++.h"
#define c std::cout<<
#define Q&a[0],&*end(a))
#define T;for(j=0;j<a.size()
int j,k;l(std::deque<int>a){auto p=[&]{c"["T;)c","+!j<<a[j++];c"]";};p();c"->";for(std::sort(Q;std::next_permutation(Q;){T-1;)if(a[j]==a[++j])goto e;c","+1/++k;p();e:;}k||c"[]";}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY7RboMgGEbv@xSOJgYGtrpLwb5DE@8MWRiiQy06wWWZ9dXnKBe9@3L@5JxfTlPSSrnvR23ksNQKfGhnz9bVEuPTJzgca9VooyIZeZbnclwcY096jUWVchK/KlNDgdDzUNJmnGFXpLRj4mT1r4LooI2LOtLTAQZXrb4WxTy8CLSKxY3RVFQxXyWoQEmRBATgl44xUXUYcyoBB3SjE0R@JhcQCkFkx9nBKw3bqB/3Pqn5tjjh9Gg8R2uZZBTpBnoTLwpRYdxx1I6@qGjIZGeM@6BWOd36@93/8KjtN6ENROsA14xkJCVvG/J0/5PNIFq7J80jpa3V3@of)

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 6 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
Œ!IẠ$Ƈ
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///oJEXPh7sWqBxr////f7ShjoGOoY5RLAA)**

#### How?

```
Œ!IẠ$Ƈ - Link: list of numbers, A
Œ!     - all permutations of A
     Ƈ - filter keep those for which:
    $  -   last two links as a monad:
  I    -     forward differences
   Ạ   -     all non-zero?
```

Comment: What do you mean by "duplicates"?

Comment: If the input is, say, `[1, 1, 0]` then the square-free permutations are `[1,0,1]` and `[1,0,1]` (where the two `1`s are swapped). I added `Q` to match up with your examples which don't include these "repeats". Totally up to you whether we are allowed to include them or not...

Comment: Ok, that's allowed.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 88 bytes

*Thanks to user `loopy walt` for `-7 bytes` and user pxeger for `-1 byte`.*
Returns a set of non-duplicate tuples. For the `nothing` case an empty `set()` is returned.

```python
lambda l:{p for p in permutations(l)if p[:len([*groupby(p)])]==p}
from itertools import*
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=VY7PCoMwDMbvPkVua0VBdxqCe45B14MysxVqG2o9iPgkuwhje6e9zfzTy0Ig-UK-X_L80OAf1swvLK_v3mN6-l501da3CnQxEqB1QKAMUOPa3ldeWdMxzRUCiUI3hon47mxP9cCISy7LkqYInW1B-cZ5a3UHqiXrfBz4uDL1yhQiSyDfMpMJBHX8U1u77-RhGkxSFhEsQU4Zz_Aw6gnSM4y4vDcd-H5tnvf6Aw)

## [Python 3.10](https://www.python.org), 95 bytes

*Thanks to user `LeopardShark` for `-1 byte`.*

```python
lambda l:{p for p in permutations(l)if all(i!=j for i,j in pairwise(p))}
from itertools import*
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=VY5BCoMwEEX3PcV0ZVIUtKsi2ItYKSl16EhiQoyUIp6kG6G0d-ptqjGbDgMzf3ifP8-PebibbqcXFqd37zA5fM9SqMtVgMwHA6gtGKAWTG1V74Qj3XZMckIQUjLaFo1nKG48JcjeqauZ4XzcoNUKyNXWaS07IGW0dbsQg4tNLqayTGPIfKdVDEHt_5RfVyYL12CqqnwDcxlLrWMYDXKE5AgDzl-OEV_TpmmdPw)

Comment: In Python 3.10 you can save a byte with `pairwise`.

Comment: `pairwise(p)` (where `pairwise` comes, conveniently, from `itertools`) does the same as `zip(p,p[1:])`. I don’t know where you could host it, though.

Comment: 89 bytes using `groupby` to check for repeats: https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=VU5LCoMwEN17itk1EQXtqgj2HsVmodS0gSQzxLgQ8STdCKW9U29TP9l0GJh5j3nvzfNDg3-gnV-yvL57L9PT96Jr09xq0MVIINEBgbJArTO9r71C2zHNlQTdWlbFd4c9NQMjLnhZrhzxKZIODSjfOo-oO1CG0Pk4BMjVVK-mVZUlkG-diQQCOv6hbd1v8sAGkRBFBEuRU9YzeRj1BOkZRrn8Nx34njbP-_wB

Comment: 88 bytes: [`lambda l:{p for p in permutations(l)if p[:len([*groupby(p)])]==p};from itertools import*`](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=VY7PCoMwDMbvPkVua0VBdxqCe45B14MysxVqG2o9iPgkuwhje6e9zfzTy0Ig-UK-X_L80OAf1swvLK_v3mN6-l501da3CnQxEqB1QKAMUOPa3ldeWdMxzRUCiUI3hon47mxP9cCISy7LkqYInW1B-cZ5a3UHqiXrfBz4uDL1yhQiSyDfMpMJBHX8U1u77-RhGkxSFhEsQU4Zz_Aw6gnSM4y4vDcd-H5tnvf6Aw)

Comment: Thank you all for your feedback!

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), 90 bytes

Returns a set of strings.

```javascript
f=(a,p=[],s=new Set)=>a.map((v,i)=>v==p[0]||f(a.filter(_=>i--),[v,...p],s))+a?s:s.add(p+a)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fczBCsIwEATQu1/R4y5Nl9SjsPoRHkORpU0kUpvQlHjpv8ei4KkIcxkeMw/JkvrZx6WZwmBLcQyiIptOJZ7sq7raBfks9JQIkJXfSmaORnfr6kDI@XGxM9z47JsGlcmKiOK2Rqzlkk6JZBgg1oKlD1MKo6Ux3MGB0apqP9Ed4mEXj/9wT76H7f5G/7C8AQ)

Comment: [88](https://tio.run/##fczBCoMwEATQe7/C4y4mS@yxEPsRHkXKYpKSYk0wkl7897RU6EkKcxkeMw/OnMbFx1XOwdhSnAYWSc/2VXV2FUQUUbdMT44AWfhPyVrHXg3b5oDJ@Wm1C9x066VEkUTeN1jzNV0SsTEQa8YyhjmFydIU7uCgV6JqvlED4ukQz//wSPbD5nijflje)

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>55</s> 53 bytes

```ruby
->l{[]|l.permutation.select{|r,*f|f.all?{|x|r!=r=x}}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y6nOjq2JkevILUot7QksSQzP0@vODUnNbmkuqZIRyutJk0vMSfHvrqmoqZI0bbItqK2tvZ/gUJadLSBjiEQGsTGcoG5II5hbOx/AA)

Thanks AZTECCO for -2 bytes

Answer (score 2):

## [Curry (PAKCS)](https://www.informatik.uni-kiel.de/%7Epakcs/), 53 bytes

```
[]#s=s
(x++a:y)#s|s==[]||a/=head s=(x++y)#(a:s)
(#[])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FclBCoAgEADAe69Y8KJoZB2FfYl4WCwpogiXIMG/W8114p1z6S/aI7fmg2DkTj5akytKcGVEH2qlAdeFZmD87xtJjlWXUAofVDtoOwEhgbcGRgOTARvaCw)

Curry supports non-deterministic operations which can return different values for the same input. This is a non-deterministic function whose different return values are the all complex permutations (including duplicates).

Answer (score 2):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 10 bytes

```
p.{s₂=}ᶜ0∧
```

A [generator](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10753/16766) predicate that takes a list through its input parameter and produces permutations (including duplicates) through its output parameter. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATMAzP9icmFjaHlsb2cy/@KGsOKCgeG6ieKKpf9wLntz4oKCPX3htpww4oin//9bMCwwLDEsMl0)

#### Explanation

```
p.{s₂=}ᶜ0∧
p           Get a permutation of the input list
 .          This is the output
  {   }ᶜ    Count the number of ways to:
   s₂        Get a length-2 sublist
     =       whose elements are equal
        0   Assert that the result is 0
         ∧  Don't try to unify 0 with the output
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), 162 bytes

Port of [@G B's Ruby answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/244114/110802) in Scala.

---

Golfed version. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bU5Na8MwDL3nV@hoQwntVeBCdxtsu4ydSilq5nQqjl1sBRJCfntqp6eNCSHQ@@C91JCjJVxuthF4J/YwLd@2hV45fOMkx1cvJ21cfbex64WEg091y05sVKxrCUVVFQv/suBLCM6SNw46kuZnaihZ@GBn9hJ7C@t7RvyDDIgj4pDMnls1GDPqllzGbTmsVk7PC0BJ7HJfRfGaEA4x0nj8lMj@msPhy7OAgamCPPeMivOqV6Wf2m5gt@5Wa/2f4MnunuxczcsD)

```scala
def u(l:List[Int])=l.permutations.filter(i).toList
def i(l:List[Int]):Boolean=l match{case Nil=>true case _::Nil=>true case x::y::xs=>if(x==y)false else i(y::xs)}
```

Ungolfed version. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVBNS8QwEL33V7xjAlJ2r4EK6klQEcTTskis0zWSpmsylRbpb69JtywVKghhCG/ex8yEUls9js3rB5WMe20cvjPgjSq0zny29Ei@blmzaVwQ1gRWuIt1d@t4L@f/GdijmORAYubHhTavjGXywoTnyfcmYlS2bL5I5twkiygcsjl8hbaSft00lrT7lYpac/k@A0CpA@HBWBSXYN/SEn5R6o9Op1SvVBdSz1QQHYoCvUSlbexSKmsTTho5GQ3Lbep4V6H9IShcea/73RN74w5phWjC5/mPEWXrxMrp09pic4Ht9DZSyn8pTvTtiT5kwzj@AA)

```scala
object Main {
  def uniquePermutations(list: List[Int]): List[List[Int]] = {
    list.permutations.filter(isUniqueConsecutive).toList
  }

  def isUniqueConsecutive(list: List[Int]): Boolean = {
    list match {
      case Nil => true
      case _::Nil => true
      case x::y::xs => if (x == y) false else isUniqueConsecutive(y::xs)
    }
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println(uniquePermutations(List(0, 1, 1, 0)))
    println(uniquePermutations(List(1, 1, 1)))
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 93 bytes

```r
\(v,m=permute::allPerms(v))for(i in 1:nrow(m)){l=v[m[i,]];if(all(l!=lag(l),na.rm=T))print(l)}
```

Prints in console, including duplicates:

> v=c(0,-2,1,0) ; a(v)

> [1]  0 -2  0  1
> [1]  0  1 -2  0
> [1]  0  1  0 -2
> [1] -2  0  1  0
> [1] -2  0  1  0
> [1]  1  0 -2  0
> [1]  1  0 -2  0
> [1]  0 -2  0  1
> [1]  0 -2  1  0
> [1]  0  1  0 -2
> [1]  0  1 -2  0